# Como puedo Calcular el Centro de un polygon con la API de Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

¿Como puedo calcular el centro de un polígono (Polygon) con la API de Google Maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puede utilizar la versión 3 de la `API` de Google Maps, es posible que desee pasar cada punto del polígono a un objeto [`LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#LatLngBounds) a través del método  extend(), y finalmente, llamar al al método `getCenter()` en el objeto `LatLngBounds`.

Considere el siguiente ejemplo:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var i;

// El triangulo de las Bermudas
var polygonCoords = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
  new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
  new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.757370),
  new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
];

for (i = 0; i < polygonCoords.length; i++) {
  bounds.extend(polygonCoords[i]);
}

// El centro del triángulo de las Bermudas - (25.3939245, -72.473816)
console.log(bounds.getCenter());
```

---

Lo que estás viendo es un objeto [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/#LatLng).

Lo que puede hacer es simplemente invocar las funciones `lat()` y `lng()`:

```
var lat = suPoligono.su_getBounds().getCenter().lat();
var lng = suPoligono.su_getBounds().getCenter().lng();
```

---

Otro Método que podría usar sería un Algoritmo:

Corre a través de todos los puntos en el polígono. Para todos los puntos encuentra:

- `x1`, la `x` coordenada más baja
- `y1`, la `y` coordenada más baja
- `x2`, la `x` coordenada más alta
- `y2`, la `y` coordenada más alta

Ahora tiene el rectángulo delimitador, y puede resolver el centro usando:

```
center.x = x1 + ((x2 - x1) / 2);
center.y = y1 + ((y2 - y1) / 2);
```

> Para mas información consulte la fuente SO: [How to get the center of a polygon in google maps v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3081021/8933039) de donde he tomado esta respuesta.